# Vuetify 2 to 3 : why did theme colors change from blue to purple when we migrated?

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

We weren't customizing Vuetify's theme colors at all, just using the default light/dark theme options.

In Vuetify 2, the primary color seemed to be blue. But in Vuetify 3, suddenly everything is purple instead of blue.

While we could just create a custom theme and override the purple, I'd like to understand why this is happening. Did they change their default theme?

As a starter, I've done this, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel:

```
createVuetify({
      theme: {
        themes: {
          light: {
            colors: {
              primary: colors.blue.darken2,
            },
          },
          dark: {
            colors: {
              primary: colors.blue.darken2,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

Comment: If you take a look at the Vuetify sources in `src/composables/theme.ts` you will notice that the primary color is purple rather than blue.

Comment: Here is a [bug report about it](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/15848) from an unhappy reporter... I'm gonna say you should change the color yourself if the new one bothers you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Ivo and Moritz for their comments above, which helped me find the right direction.

If you would like the Vuetify 2 color palette in Vuetify 3, I have recreated it based on https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/presets/#default-preset and https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/

```
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'

createVuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          secondary: colors.grey.darken3,
          accent: colors.blue.accent1,
          error: colors.red.accent2,
          info: colors.blue.base,
          success: colors.green.base,
          warning: colors.orange.darken1,
        },
      },
      dark: {
        colors: {
          primary: colors.blue.base,
          secondary: colors.grey.darken3,
          accent: colors.pink.accent1,
          error: colors.red.accent2,
          info: colors.blue.base,
          success: colors.green.base,
          warning: colors.orange.darken1,
        },
      },
    },
  }
})
```

If you'd like to achieve the above without the import:

```
createVuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: '#1976D2',
          secondary: '#424242',
          accent: '#82B1FF',
          error: '#FF5252',
          info: '#2196F3',
          success: '#4CAF50',
          warning: '#FB8C00',
        },
      },
      dark: {
        colors: {
          primary: '#2196F3',
          secondary: '#424242',
          accent: '#FF4081',
          error: '#FF5252',
          info: '#2196F3',
          success: '#4CAF50',
          warning: '#FB8C00',
        },
      },
    },
  }
})
```